# css how to put cods in a container

Tags: html, css

my css code is below:

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>


  <div class="login-help">
    <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
</div>

    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

so the view will looks like :

[image: like this pic]

So,I need two div class which I have to place inside `<div id="content"></div>`
I have tried..
but it is not creating..How can i do this?

Comment: please create fiddle rather than posting bunch of codes..it will help,

Comment: this is the jsfiddle "http://jsfiddle.net/fx4mpk5g/"..I want the login form under a div class/id with blue color..

Comment: sorry but link is broken...not working.

Comment: so you need 3 block and 3 login form.right?

Comment: in the left side I have div id= content...under this id i want two different ids which will contain the login form class..you can see the picture..I want exactly like the above picture

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear

but if you are saying that the login form is not creating try putting the css code inside the index.html which means inline it works fine

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
/*the login card css is inside the html */
 .login-card {
  padding: 40px;
  width: 274px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.login-card h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.3em;
}

.login-card input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.login-card input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  /* border-radius: 2px; */
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.login-card input[type=text]:hover, input[type=password]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.login {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 8px;
/* border-radius: 3px; */
/* -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; */
}

.login-submit {
  /* border: 1px solid #3079ed; */
  border: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,   from(#4d90fe), to(#4787ed)); */
}

.login-submit:hover {
  /* border: 1px solid #2f5bb7; */
  border: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-color: #357ae8;
  /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,   from(#4d90fe), to(#357ae8)); */
}

.login-card a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity ease 0.5s;
}

.login-card a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.login-help {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}   

/************/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f6ff;
}


.contanier {
  margin:auto;
   background: #fff;
  height: 1500px;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
   -webkit-flex: 3 1 60%;
           flex: 3 1 60%;
   -webkit-order: 2;
           order: 2;
}
#rightcol {

    position:relative;
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height: 500px;
   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
}
#content {
  background: #fff;
  position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
 margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 68%;
  height: 1500px;

   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
}


.slider {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 60px;
}

.slider ul {
  height: 8px;
}

.slider ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background: url(../img/slide_point_bg.png) no-repeat;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.slider ul li.active {
  background: url(../img/slide_point_active_bg.png) no-repeat;
}

.slider ul li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em black;
}

.list-of-resources {
  display: table;
  }

.list-of-resources > div {
  display: table-row;
}

.list-of-resources > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  /* padding: 5px 0; */
}

.list-of-resources > div > div:last-child {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.list-of-resources a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.list-of-resources a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

#registration {
  font-family:'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}

#registration .fieldset {
    border-radius: 3px;

}

 #registration legend {
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    color: white;
font-size:2em;
}

.fieldset form{
  border:3px solid black;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  padding:30px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
}
.placeholder #registration label {
    display: none;
}
 .no-placeholder #registration label{
margin-left:5px;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  color:grey;
  text-shadow:0 1px white;
  font-weight:bold;
}
/* all */
::-webkit-input-placeholder { text-shadow:1px 1px 1px white; font-weight:bold; }
::-moz-placeholder { text-shadow:0 1px 1px white; font-weight:bold; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { text-shadow:0 1px 1px white; font-weight:bold; } /* ie */
#registration input[type=text] {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 1px;
  margin:5px auto;
  background-color:#f9ebae;
    border: 1px solid silver;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    width: 100%;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition:background-color .5s ease;
-moz-transition:background-color .5s ease;
-o-transition:background-color .5s ease;
-ms-transition:background-color .5s ease;
transition:background-color .5s ease;
}
.no-placeholder #registration input[type=text] {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

#registration input[type=text]:active, .placeholder #registration input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: silver;
  background-color:white;
}

#registration input[type=submit] {
  font-family:'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  outline:none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
}

#registration input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #2980b9;
}

#registration input[type=submit]:active {
background:#5C8CA7;
}


.parsley-error-list{
background-color:#C34343;
padding: 5px 11px;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
margin-top:-5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid #870d0d;
  border-top:none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative;
  top:-1px;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #460909;
    font-weight:700;
  font-size:12px;
}
.parsley-error{
    border-color:#870d0d!important;
  border-bottom:none;
}
#registration select{
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
}
::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

  .container {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

     #rightcol, #content{display:block; width:100%;}

   .contanier {
    display:block;
      width:95%;

    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
            flex-direction: column;

   }

   #rightcol, #content {
    /* Return them to document order */
    -webkit-order: 0;
            order: 0;
   }

  #rightcol{
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
   }



  }


</style>


  </head>


<body>

  <div class="contanier">

<div id="content">
<div class="login-card">
    <h1>Log-in</h1><br>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login">
  </form>

  <div class="login-help">
    <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="login-card">
    <h1>Log-in</h1><br>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login">
  </form>

  <div class="login-help">
    <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>



<div id="rightcol">

    <div id="registration">
    <div class='fieldset'>
    <legend>put your id below</legend>
        <form action="#" method="post" data-validate="parsley">

            <div class='row'>
                <label for="email">put your id</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="yourid@example.com"  name='email' data-required="true" data-type="email" data-error-message="Your E-mail is required">
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
    </div>

    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if this not you problem please comment i can help with this

and id you want to put the login form right you should make the div id content's width more than what you have and put a float right then and then you can make the other adjustments to the css code

Comment: in the left side I have div id= content...under this id i want two different ids which will contain the login form class..you can see the picture..I want exactly like the above picture

Comment: I have dont the above..but I want two div id's..under these div id's I want to put login forms

Comment: I have edited my ques..you can see the picture.I want to do exactly like the picture

Comment: so you have to just add two divs to the code and customise it with css then you get exactly just try the code i gave and see is that what you want

Comment: I already have tried the above code..And tried two add two divs..but when I create divs then the login for disappearing..thats why I have posted the question..

Comment: oh it din happen to me anyway try increasing the width of the div id content

Comment: No,I can't increase the width of the <div id= content>...thats why asked..how can I do this?

Comment: then you can try this try putting the <div id="rightcol"> in between the <div id ="container"> and the <div id ="content"> and still it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```css
*
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        body
        {
            width: 50%;
            font-family: 'Cabin' , sans-serif;
            background-color: #f0f6ff;
        }
        
        .contanier
        {
            margin: auto;
            background: #fff; /* height: 1500px; */
            display: block; /* width: 10%; */
            -webkit-flex: 3 1 60%;
            flex: 3 1 60%;
            -webkit-order: 2;
            order: 2;
        }
        #rightcol
        {
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            height: 500px;
            -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
            flex: 1 6 20%;
            -webkit-order: 3;
            order: 3;
        }
        #content
        {
            background: #fff;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 68%;
            height: 1500px;
            -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
            flex: 1 6 20%;
            -webkit-order: 3;
            order: 3;
        }
        
        .slider
        {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            width: 60px;
        }
        
        .slider ul
        {
            height: 8px;
        }
        
        .slider ul li
        {
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
            background: url(../img/slide_point_bg.png) no-repeat;
            width: 8px;
            height: 8px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        
        .slider ul li.active
        {
            background: url(../img/slide_point_active_bg.png) no-repeat;
        }
        
        .slider ul li:hover
        {
            box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em black;
        }
        
        .list-of-resources
        {
            display: table;
        }
        
        .list-of-resources > div
        {
            display: table-row;
        }
        
        .list-of-resources > div > div
        {
            display: table-cell; /* padding: 5px 0; */
        }
        
        .list-of-resources > div > div:last-child
        {
            padding: 0 0 0 30px;
        }
        
        .list-of-resources a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .list-of-resources a:hover
        {
            color: tomato;
        }
        
        #registration
        {
            font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' , sans-serif;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        #registration .fieldset
        {
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        
        #registration legend
        {
            text-align: center;
            background: black;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 30px 0;
            border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
            color: white;
            font-size: 2em;
        }
        
        .fieldset form
        {
            border: 3px solid black;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 30px 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
        }
        .placeholder #registration label
        {
            display: none;
        }
        .no-placeholder #registration label
        {
            margin-left: 5px;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            color: grey;
            text-shadow: 0 1px white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        /* all */
        ::-webkit-input-placeholder
        {
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        ::-moz-placeholder
        {
            text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        /* firefox 19+ */
        :-ms-input-placeholder
        {
            text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        /* ie */
        #registration input[type=text]
        {
            padding: 15px 20px;
            border-radius: 1px;
            margin: 5px auto;
            background-color: #f9ebae;
            border: 1px solid silver;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.8);
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease;
            -moz-transition: background-color .5s ease;
            -o-transition: background-color .5s ease;
            -ms-transition: background-color .5s ease;
            transition: background-color .5s ease;
        }
        .no-placeholder #registration input[type=text]
        {
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
        
        #registration input[type=text]:active, .placeholder #registration input[type=text]:focus
        {
            outline: none;
            border-color: silver;
            background-color: white;
        }
        
        #registration input[type=submit]
        {
            font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' , sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            outline: none;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            padding: 10px;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-top: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
        }
        
        #registration input[type=submit]:hover
        {
            background-color: #2980b9;
        }
        
        #registration input[type=submit]:active
        {
            background: #5C8CA7;
        }
        
        
        .parsley-error-list
        {
            background-color: #C34343;
            padding: 5px 11px;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid #870d0d;
            border-top: none;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: relative;
            top: -1px;
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #460909;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .parsley-error
        {
            border-color: #870d0d !important;
            border-bottom: none;
        }
        #registration select
        {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        ::-moz-focus-inner
        {
            border: 0;
        }
        
        .login-card
        {
            padding: 40px;
            width: 274px;
            background-color: #F7F7F7;
            margin: 0 auto 10px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .login-card h1
        {
            font-weight: 100;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 2.3em;
        }
        
        .login-card input[type=submit]
        {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .login-card input[type=text], input[type=password]
        {
            height: 44px;
            font-size: 16px;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0; /* border-radius: 2px; */
            padding: 0 8px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        .login-card input[type=text]:hover, input[type=password]:hover
        {
            border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
            border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }
        
        .login
        {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: 'Arial' , sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            height: 36px;
            padding: 0 8px; /* border-radius: 3px; */ /* -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; */
        }
        
        .login-submit
        {
            /* border: 1px solid #3079ed; */
            border: 0px;
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            background-color: #4d90fe; /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,   from(#4d90fe), to(#4787ed)); */
        }
        
        .login-submit:hover
        {
            /* border: 1px solid #2f5bb7; */
            border: 0px;
            text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            background-color: #357ae8; /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,   from(#4d90fe), to(#357ae8)); */
        }
        
        .login-card a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #666;
            font-weight: 400;
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
            opacity: 0.6;
            transition: opacity ease 0.5s;
        }
        
        .login-card a:hover
        {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        
        .login-help
        {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1000px)
        {
        
            .container
            {
                width: 90%;
            }
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-width: 700px)
        {
        
            #rightcol, #content
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }
        
            .contanier
            {
                display: block;
                width: 95%;
                -webkit-flex-flow: column;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        
            #rightcol, #content
            {
                /* Return them to document order */
                -webkit-order: 0;
                order: 0;
            }
        
            #rightcol
            {
                min-height: 50px;
                max-height: 50px;
            }
        
        
        
        }
        
        #Div1
        {
            float: left;
        }
        #Div2
        {
            float: right;
        }
```

```html
<div class="contanier">
        <div id="Div1">
            <div class="login-card" style="float: left">
                <h1>
                    Log-in</h1>
                <br />
                <form>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login">
                </form>
                <div class="login-help">
                    <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Div2">
            <div id="Div3">
                <div class='fieldset'>
                    <legend>put your id below</legend>
                    <form action="#" method="post" data-validate="parsley">
                    <div class='row'>
                        <label for="email">
                            put your id</label><br />
                        <input type="text" placeholder="yourid@example.com" name='email' data-required="true"
                            data-type="email" data-error-message="Your E-mail is required">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Div4">
            <div class="login-card" style="float: left">
                <h1>
                    Log-in</h1>
                <br />
                <form>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login">
                </form>
                <div class="login-help">
                    <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

try this snippet. It will create two login divs on the left and one 'put your id' div on right. you can create a blank HTML file to test this snippet. if you run this snippet in this browser, you might see the divs one below another due to width of result section, but works fine on the full screen page.